# Use ANTLR based parser in PMD (to implement a Apex language module)

Tags: salesforce, antlr, apex, pmd, javacc

We're working on a language module (fork) for the Salesforce.com language Apex. It's a proprietary language where no open grammar is available. What is available is an ANTLR based parser library under the Eclipse Public License that I would like to use.

**How would we do this technically? Is there any example or tutorial on how to use a custom parser? I found only JJTree/JavaCC based code and guess some kind of adapter is needed. I can't imagine that nobody has used ANTLR with PMD before.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit late, but still for completeness.

ANTLR support on PMD is [in the official roadmap](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/wiki/Project-Ideas-%5BMature%5D#full-antlr-support), but still on a very early planning stage.

On the other hand, Apex is now fully supported on PMD thanks to the works of the original poster and other talented developers.